# Download file in Android using ProgressbarDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to develop a simple application for download using `DownloadManager` but I need to do some changes, I want to download using `ProgressbarDialog` so how to do.

```
class DownloadReceiver

if(downloader == null) return;
        long completeId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
        if(completeId == downloadTaskId){
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(downloadTaskId);
            Cursor cur = downloader.query(query);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    //Download the task has been completed, remove
                    new VersionPersistent(context).clear();
                    String uriString = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    File apkFile = new File(Uri.parse(uriString).getPath());
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    installIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    context.startActivity(installIntent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.download_failure, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            cur.close();
```

and also 
download and install

```
if ( latestVersion == null || !isNetworkActive() ) return;
        downloader = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadTaskId);
        Cursor cur = downloader.query(query);
        // Download tasks already exists
        if(cur.moveToNext()) return;
        DownloadManager.Request task = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(latestVersion.targetUrl));
        String apkName = extractName(latestVersion.targetUrl);
        String title = String.format("%s - v%s", apkName,latestVersion.name);
        task.setTitle(title);
        task.setDescription(latestVersion.feature);
        task.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        task.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        task.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, apkName);
        downloadTaskId = downloader.enqueue(task);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you want to show progress bar to show the progress of download?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: This code is working @Amy

Comment: now you just want to show progress dialog?

Comment: Yes sir i want to show download progress in progessbardialog @Ganesh Kumar

Comment: @NikunjKacha did you solve your problem?

Comment: did you check given solution?

Comment: @Amy yes sir i will check

Answer (score 1):

USE this class to show progress bar , this will give you an idea for downloading an image.

**DownloadImageTask.java**

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** Reference to the view which should receive the image */
    private final WeakReference imageRef;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageRef = new WeakReference(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Wait", "Downloading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            // We open the connection
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            // we convert the inputStream into bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageRef != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageRef.get();
            if (imageView != null &amp;&amp; bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Error while downloading the image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**give permission in AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want using progressDialog, does that mean you don't need to download in the background ?
My solution is:
using `AsyncTask`
init the profressDialog before you call `task.execute()`
then show the dialog in `onPreExecute`
download file `doInBackfround`
update progess in `onProgressUpdate`
and dosomething you want when download complete in `onPostExecute`

you can learn `AsyncTask` and `HttpURLConnection` and `IO Stream`

Answer (score 0):

Use Asynctask for this. Try this.

```
private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Your File Download Code here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
             pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
             pd.show();
       }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DownloadManager's

```
   DownloadManager.query(DownloadManager.Query)
```

This gives you a Cursor to browse the columns COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES   (Total size of the download in bytes) and COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR    (Number of bytes download so far).

With this information, you'll have the details to update the ProgressBarDialog.

Comment: I think you should run the query in an AsyncTask and stop the querying when you receive the intent ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, see an error in COLUMN_REASON, or STATUS_SUCCESSFUL or STATUS_FAILED in COLUMN_STATUS.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working sample code. I use SeekBar instead of ProgressBar. Hope this help

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.downloadmanager" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStartDownload"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="startDownload"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancelDownload"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="cancelDownload"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonViewDownloads"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="viewDownloads"

            android:text="View" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.downloadmanager;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DownloadManager mDownloadManager;
    private long mDownloadReference;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private static Cursor mCursor;
    private static boolean mDownloading = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        // Set filter to only when download is complete and register broadcast receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startDownload(View view) {        
        mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.100/files/test.txt");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

        // Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        // Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        // Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
        request.setTitle("My Download");
        // Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
        request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager...");
        // Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.txt");

        // Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
        mDownloadReference = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mDownloading = true;

                while (mDownloading) {
                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(mDownloadReference);

                    mCursor = mDownloadManager.query(q);
                    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();

                        int bytes_downloaded = mCursor.getInt(mCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                        int bytes_total = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                        if (mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                            mDownloading = false;
                        }

                        final double dl_progress = ((bytes_downloaded * 100) / bytes_total);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mSeekBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (mCursor != null) {
                        mCursor.close();
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void cancelDownload(View view) {
        mDownloading = false;
        if (mDownloadManager != null) {
            mDownloadManager.remove(mDownloadReference);
        }
        mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    public void viewDownloads(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            if (mDownloadReference == referenceId) {
                Uri uri = mDownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(mDownloadReference);
                if (uri != null) {
                    String mimeType = mDownloadManager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(mDownloadReference);
                    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("FileName", file.getName());
                        jsonObject.put("FilePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
                        jsonObject.put("FileSize", file.length());
                        jsonObject.put("MimeType", mimeType);
                        String msg = "Download completed! \n\n" + jsonObject.toString(5);
                        mTextView.setText(msg);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        mTextView.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```